# Bad HTTP request performance on Windows Phone 7 device

Tags: silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I'm porting a game from Silverlight to Windows Phone 7 and using polling HTTP requests as my connection to the server. It seems the performance of HTTP requests (either WebClient or HttpWebRequest) on device is extremely bad. Emulator performs ok.

I've made a super-simple test program that continuously makes HTTP GET of a simple text/plain content.

Running the program on WP7 emulator gives me dozens of requests per second but on device (HTC HD7) only about 1/sec which is not good enough. I've tried with GPRS and WLAN connection with similar results. Also both WebClient and HttpWebRequest approaches give the same result.

To compare, an Android phone in the same networks performs much, much better.

Are there some known limitations in WP7 Silverlight network performance? Do they differ from device to device? Are there any workarounds?

This is a huge showstopper for my application.

EDIT: When the phone is connected to the PC, requests take ~40ms. When using GPRS/WLAN, requests take 500+ms. As mentioned, Android is super-fast without cable, probably around 50ms.

Comment: What's the performance like when you connect your phone to your PC with Zune running?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that. The performance is excellent when the phone is connected to the PC with USB cable.

Comment: Sounds like your phone is throttling the network connectivity. I'm not sure if this is a device/update specific problem or not. Are you running NoDo?

Comment: I'm running the latest update that has been available via Zune for HTC HD7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your network. Depending on the amounts of data and network speed (in your case - GPRS and WLAN), the performance indeed can vary drastically. When the phone is connected through the USB, you are using the local Ethernet connection and that's why the performance is good.

To solve the problem, you need to:

a) make sure that the network is good. Don't try it on your app only. See how other sites load, how other Internet-dependent applications perform.

b) re-model the way you are initiating HTTP requests. Try to reduce the frequency and (if possible) - amounts of transmitted data.

Comment: I doubt my Wifi network per se is the culprit. The best comparison is with an Android phone with a similar test program. The performance on Android is roughly 10 times better. Of course there might be some compatibility issues with the phone and my Wifi AP and I could test it in other networks as well. Remodeling the HTTP requests probably is not a viable option though.

Comment: Here is another poor soul with the same problem: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/69621/441637.aspx